# Google Apps Script debug mode not available from script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I can't start my script in debug mode in script editor. The code itself works but the debug icon is "grey".  Any advice would be appreciated.

Solution:
The function right to the debug icon was choosen. After choosing doGet-function the debug mode was available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Spreadsheet script: debug icon disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750847/google-spreadsheet-script-debug-icon-disabled)

Answer (score 1):

Select a function from the function dropdown menu.

With a function selected you will be able to run in debug mode.

Comment: Keeping your advice in mind, My blank debugger window opens for a second and then disappear. What could be the possible reasons and how to overcome this? @AndrewFogg