# Google Spreadsheet script: debug icon disabled

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first attempt at creating a google spreadsheet script.  I am following this tutorial:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section2

I can't get the csv to load and I'm attempting to debug.

I found a blog entry that says this:

> ...you can set a breakpoint on any line of code, just by clicking on the line number.
>   Then, simply run the script using the 'bug' toolbar icon instead of the usual 'play' button, and the script will run only as far as the first breakpoint.

However, the debug icon button in the toolbar is grayed out.

Any suggestions as to how I might enable this?  A google search has turned up nothing.  I am using Google Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43.

Comment: is the "play" button also grayed or not ?

Comment: yes, the play button is also grayed out.

Comment: I'm running it by selecting the Run pull down and then selecting the function.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

select a function in the dropdown list

[image]

Comment: Not 'duh' at all. There's nothing in the tutorial that mentions this step, and nothing in the UI that makes it obvious that this is required. I honestly don't even understand why developers need to do this... it seems to run the function straight away, which isn't very helpful when trying to debug a spreadsheet.

Comment: You can set break points to check execution step by step and see the variables values see doc here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that breakpoints don't seem to work when code is invoked by Google Sheets. I have found, however, that once initialisation is out of the way, code in the debugger will interact with the spreadsheet, even when it's invoked by the debug icon. I normally don't code separate functions for menu items when they just call other functions, but it's the best way I've found for debugging Google Sheets—the debugger dropdown, essentially, acts as a menu. The only thing I still haven't been able to do is set breakpoints for code invoked on load. Any suggestions for that?